# oracle apex developer toolbar clarification

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Can't believe I'm having to ask this but what started out as (what I thought was) a simple question that would take seconds to google the answer yet can't find a thing. My question is this:

I build an application and run it from inside Apex developer - the developer toolbar is displayed. Great.
I log out of Apex developer (could also shutdown browser)
I directly type the url of my application into a fresh browser session acting as a normal user - so no longer logged into Apex nor running as a developer and yet the developer toolbar is still displayed. Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are not closing your workspace session by making a real log out. The toolbar will appear as long as the workspace session is active and the application availability is with the option "Available with Developer Toolbar" . If you don't want the toolbar to appear at all, you can disable it by editing the application properties.

[image]

In your specif case, I would try the following to be sure that the toolbar does not appear:

- Login into your worskpace
- Open the Application Builder and press Run application
- If you have the application availability by default ( with toolbar ), the Developer toolbar will appear as long as your session in the workspace is active.
- Log out from your workspace
- Refresh the page in your application ( be sure that you have effectively logged out from the worskpace )
- The toolbar should not appear anymore.

I did this test in Apex 5.1.4 , 19c and 20c and it works without issues.

Comment: @Steve Says, did you try to follow the steps ?

Comment: yes I followed your steps and it worked a treat. My problem was I wasn't fully logged out of the workspace. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: can you  accept the answer and upvote it ? thank you